# HTML form submit button within textfield

Tags: html, css, forms, submit

Im new to CSS and HTML and learning html forms right now. I was wondering if it is possible to put a submit button within the text field. Much like how google has their voice search button in their search field.

and if so, how do i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/9R2XC/

You need to put the element in absolute position and lay it on top of each other.

```
position: absolute; // absolute position of element
left: -20px; // lay the element on the search box
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You cant put it within the element so to speak, but you can [**position it**](http://jsfiddle.net/8xape/)

HTML

```
<input type='text' />
<input type='submit' value='GO'/>
```

CSS

```
input{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
input:last-child{
    left:-40px;
}
```

Note that this is just one of the ways you can create this effect (you dont have to use a submit input element for example).

Comment: Thanks mate! works perfect, will accept the answer as soon as it lets me (y)